# drop down change fire show same element

Tags: jquery

```
<span id="row-0" class="row">
   <span class="Foo">
      <select name="first[]">
            <option value="XX">XX</option>
            <option value="YY">YY</option>
            <option value="ZZ">ZZ</option>
      </select>
   </span>
   <span class="Foo">
       <select name="second[]">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="AA">AA</option>
            <option value="BB">BB</option>
            <option value="CC">CC</option>
        </select>
   </span>
</span>
```

I have a row which have two different select. When ever both filled I want to show another row. How can it be achieved using jquery?

Comment: What have you tried? and BTW the first select doesn't have a default value.

Comment: how you mean *"I want to show another row"* ??  Please explain a bit better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by adding a new row. But generally, this is what you are looking for.  You need to catch the change event of the last dropdown and create a copy of the row and append to its parent. Assuming your row span is inside a div with class `container`, This should work for your HTML markup you provided.

```
$(function(){   
    $(".container").on("change",".Foo:last",function(){
       var item=$(this);
       var rowClone=item.closest(".row").clone();   
       item.closest(".container").append(rowClone);
    });
});
```

Here is a sample : http://jsfiddle.net/Dbq3D/12/

This wont validate whether both selects are filled because the mark up you provided has the first dropdown filled with a value already.

Comment: (+1) I can imagine now another question saying: "yes nice, nut now I want to remove already selected options from the new ones" :)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. how about making first option "make your choice"

```
$("select").change(function(){
   if ($("#row-0").find(':selected').not(:contains('make your choice')).size()>1)  
     {$("#row-0").append('<br/> yournewLine');}  
});
```

...it seems the natural way to me.. I hope it helps you

---

@Roko C. Buljan saying: " I can imagine now another question saying: "yes nice, nut now I want to remove already selected options from the new ones" :)". I guess this would be also simple by using the :selected - Selector like :

```
$("select").change(function(){
    /*better read the value first*/
   $(":selected").not(:contains('make your choice')).remove();
});
```